# angularJs ng-repeat using the same name for input and marking this input invalid

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using the following control inside the ng-repeat directive:

```html
<input type="number" name="pcSplit"
   ng-model="currentItem['pcSplit'+n]"
   class="form-control"
   min="0"
   ng-max="currentItem.monday0"
   data-sm:number data-sm:number-format
   ng-disabled="currentItem['prCtr'+n]===0"
   ng-blur="calculateTotalFlatAmount($event)"
   data-accuracy="2"
   ng-if="(currentItem.splitType !==1)" />
```

My problem is that I want to set validity of the element I'm leaving to false if the total is more than some amount. I'm passing the $event and `$event.target` or `$event.currentTarget` seems to point to my DOM element, but it doesn't have `$setValidity` method I'm using. If I just use the name of the control, then the very last control is set to invalid. Is there a way to get the element if I name them the same in the `ng-repeat` loop?

This is my current code that doesn't work

```js
let element = event.target; // DOM element

if (element.value.length === 0) {
  element.value = "0.00";
}

if ($scope.currentItem.splitType === 2) {
  total = getProfitCenterTotal($scope.currentItem);                

  if ($scope.form.editItemProfitCenterForm.profitCenters.pcSplit) {
    if (total <= $scope.currentItem.monday0) {
        element.$setValidity("total", true);
    } else {
        element.$setValidity("total", false);
    }
  }
```

I'm guessing I may need to have different names for my controls which would make slightly more complex code in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't use `$setValidity` on elements. You are correct you should use different names, but that won't necessarily make your code complex.

I suggest using the ng-repeat's `$index` parameter to set the name so it's unique, than retrieve that name from the element and find your input in the form model.

Changes needed in HTML:

```
<input type="number" name="pcSplit{{$index}}"
```

Changes needed in controller:

```
if ($scope.form.editItemProfitCenterForm.profitCenters[element.name]) {
   if (total <= $scope.currentItem.monday0) {
      $scope.form.editItemProfitCenterForm.profitCenters[element.name].$setValidity("total", true);
   } else {
      $scope.form.editItemProfitCenterForm.profitCenters[element.name].$setValidity("total", false);
   }
}
```

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: I was coming this morning to this exact conclusion. I'm going to try that later today and let you know. I also do not need the profitCenters form then since I'm using different names for controls.